# delete entities which are not represented on the server side

Tags: breeze

I want to remove all entities which are not represented on the server anymore (e.g when another client deletes it).

My current approach is to delete all entities from a specific type which are not returned after a query anymore:

1. Get and cache all local entities from specific type
2. Make the query
3. Compare old entities with new entities which are returned from the query and detach it from entity manager

This seems a little work for me and i wonder if there not an easier way (maybe breeze already has something) to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question.  We refer to these types of entities as "ghosts".  They are entities that are  queried from a server by one user and later deleted by another user.  The entities on the first client have now become 'ghosts'.

We have an existing feature request that would automatically 'detach' these ***if and only if*** a  primary key requery occurs. The reason for this is that unless the entity was fetched by primary key we cannot determine that it is a ghost. We have not yet implemented this feature but are considering it for one of the near term releases.  Would this feature be of use to you?

Comment: yup. that would be great!

Comment: hi jay, i'm also interested in this topic. it's not 100% clear to me what you mean with "primary key requery"? i assume it's a query whicht gets just one entity identified by its primary key but i'm not sure.

Comment: ok thanks jay.
i just got something in my mind to solve this issue in a more general way.
here goes my "ghostbusters" approach ;) :
- When issuing a query also save a hash of the query signature
- Then attach this hash to every resulting entity
- Then subsequent calls of the same query signature can check for ghosts and bust them.

i know it doesn't cover all the use cases but at least in my scenarios i use a lot of requerying (of the the same queries) to get fresh entities of the server.

Comment: I like the idea but what about another query that also returns some ( but not all) of the same entities.  Which hash do we apply to those entities that intersect both queries?

Comment: not sure how string.indexOf() performs in js but why not put together a string like "Q2Q4Q2Q1Q3" which would mean tat the entity was created using Query 1 then Query 4 then ... then an indexOf('Q4') would be enough to check